# Get Value From Parent Node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-child

I'm trying to get the Social Security of a parent.I tried this code but it returns empty, but I know the value is not empty.

```
<xsl:call-template name="render-Employee">
    <xsl:with-param name="ssno" select="normalize-space(SocialSecurityNumber)"></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="firstName" select="normalize-space(FirstName)"></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="middleName" select="normalize-space(MiddleName)"></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="lastName" select="normalize-space(LastName)"></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="creationDate" select="ChangeDate"></xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:for-each select="Dependents">
    <xsl:for-each select="Dependent">
      <xsl:call-template name="render-Dependent">
        <xsl:with-param name="recordType" select="'BN'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="employeeSsno" select="normalize-space(ancestor::Employee[1]/@SocialSecurityNumber)"/>
```

sample xml

```
<Employee>
    <EntityKey>
      <EntitySetName>Employees</EntitySetName>
      <EntityContainerName>...</EntityContainerName>
      <EntityKeyValues>
        <EntityKeyMember>
          <Key>EmployeeId</Key>
          <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">873</Value>
        </EntityKeyMember>
        <EntityKeyMember>
          <Key>CompanyId</Key>
          <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">33</Value>
        </EntityKeyMember>
      </EntityKeyValues>
    </EntityKey>
    <Dependents>
      <Dependent>
        <EntityKey>
          ....
        </EntityKeyValues>
        </EntityKey>
        ...
        <SocialSecurityNumber>123456789</SocialSecurityNumber>
        ...
      </Dependent>
    </Dependents>
    <EmployeeId>873</EmployeeId>
    ...
    <SocialSecurityNumber>000000000</SocialSecurityNumber>
    ...
  </Employee>
```

Comment: Please can you provide an example of the input XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath expression says

```
ancestor::Employee[1]/@SocialSecurityNumber
```

but in your example XML `SocialSecurityNumber` is an element, not an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, the Employees SSN is an element, not an attribute, so you need to change the xpath to

```
select="normalize-space(ancestor::Employee[1]/SocialSecurityNumber/text())"
```

Comment: Out of habit really - it depends on what your call template expects. e.g. if the input XML was `<SocialSecurityNumber>000000000<anotherElement someAttribs=
"blah" /></SocialSecurityNumber>` then you probably only want the 1st `text()[1]` (i.e. '000000000') passed to the template.